# Php code for image path json encode

Tags: php, android, mysql, json

I am new to android. I am working with json data and have faced a problem which i can not get rid of. I have some image path like:`uploads/6152_File_map.jpg` and description:`this is map` in mysql database, I want to convert this image path and description in to json data. My php code is as follows:

```
<?php
require("opener_db.php");   
$sql = "select * from imagename";
$res=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
$result=array();
while($row= mysqli_fetch_array($res))
{
  array_push($result,array('image'=>$row[1],'description'=>$row[2]));

}
echo json_encode(array("zishan"=>$result));
mysqli_close($con);
```

when i executed the code in my local host i got the following output:

```
{"zishan":[]}
```

PHP code is working for any types of conversion of json data, but not working for image path. Can any one please kindly help me, if there is any wrong in my question. Please forgive me, thanks to all.

Comment: FIrst... give an example of path you use.
Do you use windows ?

Comment: thanks for your comment ,my image path is:'uploads/6152_File_map.jpg' and description:'this is map'  this are two data in my sql database.

Comment: and var_dump($result, $row[1], $row[2]); ?

Comment: Try to use names of the columns here. It's very unreadable. Something like `$row['name']` instead of `$row[1]`. This way you know what variable you're working with. And it will be easier for us to answer your question.

Comment: And add "or die(mysqli_error())" after your mysqli_query()

Comment: thank you for your answer,i have used following code  array_push($result,array('image'=>$row[image],'description'=>$row[description]));  instead of  array_push($result,array('image'=>$row[1],'description'=>$row[2])); but i get no result.

Comment: and var_dump ? and mysqli_error ?

Comment: thank you for your answer,i used it but no changed happened.

Comment: Are you sure to looking the correct file, correct tablename ?
try to "echo" debugging.
You query work fine in mysql console ?
What saying your http log ?

Comment: Why have you two $con and $conn variable ??? mysqli_close doesn't should use $conn previously used by your query ?

Comment: thanks,i changed $conn to $con  but no change is happened.

Comment: put your integral code (opener_db.php too) in a "pastebin.com" or "sprunge.us" please. Have you checked you http log "tail -f /var/log/apache2/your_error_log" (replace apache2 by nginx if you using it)

Comment: Did you check you have some path in `image` column in database?